# Avro schema : List of generic types

Tags: java, schema, avro

Here's Java equivalent of what I am trying to write a schema for, in Avro:

```
abstract class Vehicle {}
class Bike extends Vehicle {}
class Car extends Vehicle {}
class Bus extends Vehicle {}
```

Now, I want to have a file with `List` of Vehicles, e.g.:

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles = ;
```

Elements in the list can be either of Bike, Car or Bus. Now, comparing this to Avro schema, I can see the [Array type](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Arrays) so I might have to write something like this (sorry for the hopelessness on the Avro part, I haven't worked with it before):

```
{
  "name" : "vehicles",
  "type" : "array",
  "items" : {
    "name" : "???"
  }
}
```

This is as far as I could go, is there any way to specify that the items can be one of Bike, Car or Bus?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using union in items as

```
"items":["Bike","Car","Bus"]
```